# Getting .NET Client to recognize authentication session cookie

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I am using "RememberMe=true", and would like my service client to re-use the open session if it's available.  I got the bulk of the code from the link below - this code works but authentication fails every time at first and re-authenticates.  Do I have to send the ss-pid cookie somehow?

One more note: this is a **WinForms** client accessing my servicestack service.

[ServiceStack JsonServiceClient OnAuthenticationRequired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761937/servicestack-jsonserviceclient-onauthenticationrequired)

My code

```
    Private Shared _UserName As String = "xxxxx"
    Private Shared _Password As String = "yyyyy"

    Private Shared _clientAuthenticationRequested As New Action(Of WebRequest)(AddressOf InteractiveAuthentication)

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property ServiceClient() As JsonServiceClient
        Get
            If _serviceClient Is Nothing Then
                _serviceClient = New JsonServiceClient(ServiceContext.ServiceUrl)
                _serviceClient.OnAuthenticationRequired = _clientAuthenticationRequested
                _serviceClient.UserName = _UserName
                _serviceClient.Password = _Password

                //service requiring authentication
                Dim v = _serviceClient.Get(Of Tonto.Svc.Model.AppConstants)(
                    New Tonto.Svc.Model.AppConstants())

            End If
            Return _serviceClient
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Shared Sub InteractiveAuthentication(sourcerequest As System.Net.WebRequest)

        Dim v = _serviceClient.Send(Of ServiceStack.AuthenticateResponse)(
            New ServiceStack.Authenticate() With {
                .UserName = _UserName,
                .Password = _Password,
                .RememberMe = True})             

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have the client remember your session between the creation of clients out of the box. The `RememberMe` option will not work here, as the client does not have a persistent cookie store like a web browser.

You can however access the cookie store of the client, after you have authenticated then read the session value cookie, and restore it in future client instances. Essentially you provide the persistence layer.

Sorry it's c# not VB. But I think the concept should be clear enough.

```cs
  var host = "http://localhost:9001";
  JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient(host);

  // Authenticate with the service
  client.Post(new Authenticate { UserName = "test", Password = "password" });

  // Read the session cookie after successfully authenticating
  var cookies = client.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(host));
  var sessionCookieValue = cookies["ss-id"].Value;

  // Store the value of sessionCookieValue, so you can restore this session later

  client = null;
```

So if you were to save the `ss-id` value to a file, you can restore the value when the application is started, then add it back into the client's cookie store before making requests.

```cs
  // Another client instance ... we will reuse the session
  JsonServiceClient anotherClient = new JsonServiceClient(host);

  // Restore the cookie
  anotherClient.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("ss-id", sessionCookieValue, "/", "localhost"));

  // Try access a secure service
  anotherClient.Get(new TestRequest());
```